# Why java.lang.AutoCloseable interface is added in Java 1.7

Tags: java, interface

`java.lang.AutoCloseable` interface is same as `java.io.Closeable` interface. So what is need to add new `java.lang.AutoCloseable` interface in Java 1.7.

Comment: To make our life easier.

Answer (score 1):

> in Java SE 7 and later, implements the interface
>   java.lang.AutoCloseable. Because the BufferedReader instance is
>   declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed
>   regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly
>   (as a result of the method BufferedReader.readLine throwing an
>   IOException).

It's used for auto closing the resources regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly in Java 7, check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details.

And,

> The Closeable interface extends the AutoCloseable interface. The close
>   method of the Closeable interface throws exceptions of type
>   IOException while the close method of the AutoCloseable interface
>   throws exceptions of type Exception. Consequently, subclasses of the
>   AutoCloseable interface can override this behavior of the close method
>   to throw specialized exceptions, such as IOException, or no exception
>   at all.